# Why am I getting this error in "pip install ephem"?

Tags: installation, terminal, python, pip, runtime-error

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/12/knn7d9c16gd1f0jkjr740q100000gn/T/pip_build_Philip/ephem/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/12/knn7d9c16gd1f0jkjr740q100000gn/T/pip-2XJEpS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/12/knn7d9c16gd1f0jkjr740q100000gn/T/pip_build_Philip/ephem
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Philip/.pip/pip.log
```

At the end of the installation messages, it's giving me these errors. Is one of my directories that should be here, missing? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing xcrun, try the following `xcode-select --install`